# Kubernetes not able to start docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this docker app which was conditioned to run using docker-compose. Due to company policy we cannot use docker in production VMs directly and I have to use it when orchestrated through kubernetes.

I converted docker-compose to kubernetes config using kompose convert
This java app in its implementation refers to **DOCKER_ENGINE_URL**, the value presently given is `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. This run into errors when minikube’s pod try to spin up the pod with errors

```
INFO org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: Connection refused
INFO org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
INFO org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: Connection refused
```

I came across this [k8s blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/) which says docker runtime inside k8s was removed from v1.20 and I am using v1.22
Other than downgrading the version, what value of DOCKER_ENGINE_URL can I use to make it work?
PS- I am total beginner to both docker and k8s

Comment: Why you really need DOCKER_ENGINE_URL in the Kubernetes?

Comment: ...and can you rewrite your application to avoid needing access to the container engine at all?